# Crowdsale Contract Merged into Token Contract

Tags: solidity, crowdsale

Is it safe to have the Crowdsale and Token contract combined as one contract instead of two separate ones? Are there any drawbacks/advantages of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

To me, the drawback is that it makes it harder for someone to read your contract and understand it. The crowdsale lasts only a short time, while the token will (hopefully) be used for much longer. It's nice if the token contract is just a token contract. Keeping that code short and simple will make it easier for others to verify that it does what it's supposed to.